# Zero-inflation with sklearn and continuous target?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, supervised-learning, zero-inflation

My current data have quite a large amount of zeros (~60%), and I'm thinking of trying to implement a zero-inflated model of sorts with sklearn. While I've used zero-inflated poisson/negative binomial models before, my current target variable is continuous, non-count observations and does not follow those distributions.

This is what I'm currently thinking of doing, and I was hoping someone could weigh in on if this is a valid approach or if there were any other suggestions.

1. Train a classifier to classify an observation as either 0 or not.
2. Train a new model to predict target values

I'd use cross-validation for model selection in both steps and 2 different evaluation metrics (like precision for #1 and RMSE for #2).

Does anyone have any other suggestions?